# How do you say “with what” in this case?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

I’m trying to write the following exchange in German:

> I need your help.
>   With what?

I know how to translate the first sentence, but the second one is puzzling me. It seems to be one of these two choices:

> Ich brauche deine Hilfe.
>   Mit was?

or

> Ich brauche deine Hilfe.
>   Womit?

Both of these translate to *with what*, but it’s not clear what each of these is used for. Which one makes more sense in this particular case, or is there another choice which is more suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends a little on what you’re saying. Different prepositional objects can be added to *helfen*:

- *jemandem **bei** etwas helfen* — This is the most idiomatic way of saying *to help somebody with something*. If you have this expression in mind, the question is:

  > Bei was?

  or better:

  > Wobei?
- *jemandem **mit** etwas helfen* — This has a slight undertone of you using something to help somebody. It is not as common. Consequently, the questions are either:

  > Mit was?

  or better:

  > Womit?
- *jemandem **zu** etwas helfen* — *to help somebody arrive at something.* In this case, the final product is important. Naturally, use:

  > Zu was?

  or better:

  > Wozu?

In case you didn’t already conclude the rule: You can always use *preposition + was*, but it is generally better style (and should always be done in written texts) to use the *wo* prepositional pronoun such as *wobei/womit/wozu*.

Comment: Looks like "wobei" was the one I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: "wofür" will fit as well, and  would be *my* favorite

Answer (score 1):

Beides ist möglich, und *wobei/bei was, wofür/für was, wozu/zu was* und  *hoffentlich nicht heute/wieso immer ich* oder *hast Du keine Frau/Du weißt von meinem Bandscheibenvorfall*?

Da man nicht weiß, wobei, kann man auch nicht die passendste Frage wählen, wobei es wahrscheinlich weitere Möglichkeiten gibt, die mir nur jetzt nicht einfallen. *Wobei* würde ich bevorzugen.

Comment: Heute habe ich "Bandscheibenvorfall" gelernt.